# DDD & stateful communication

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design, rtsp

We have a very specialized application in our environment that is responsible for managing IP based surveillance devices, such as IP cameras, analytics devices. If a new device is added to the management database, a RTSP (stateful TCP based protocol) client should automatically connect to the device and setup streams. The communication is being handled asynchronously, bi-directional and needs to be constantly monitored in order to detect connection drops immediately.

Where does such a concern fit into the DDD world? AFAIK, the RTSP protocol is a infrastructure concern and the communication handling can be done in a application service, however certain domain rules must be applied for various aspects. Also, the whole RTSP stuff is implemented in a library, so I guess I have to create wrappers for it.
Do infrastructure services throw domain events, in order to inform domain event handlers about e.g. connection losses?

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think so, this is comparable to a web application where in the Controller (MVC speak) is a infrastructure concern, it deals with the HTTP protocol, however it forms a command in the language of the domain ([CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) speak) and fires it off on the command bus for the domain layer to process. At some point a infrastructure component must convert a event into its domain equivalent and then send it across for the domain layers to process.